# Plot dictionary of dictionaries in one barplot

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I've got a dictionary that looks like this

```
d = {
    'a' : {'L1':2, 'L2':5, 'L3':8},
    'b' : {'L1':4, 'L2':7, 'L3':10},
    'c' : {'L1':19, 'L2':0, 'L3':1},
}
```

I would like to have a plot where the x axis contains my keys and each key has 3 barplots that correspond to the values of L1, L2 and L3.
All in all, my plot would contain 9 bars grouped by the key (so 3 groups of 3 bars).

So far, what I could do was convert my dictionary to a dataframe and then use seaborn's barplot for each of the keys but that leaves my with 3 different plots.

Is it possible to have one plot with all the informations ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you try: `df = pd.DataFrame(d); df.plot(subplots=True, kind='bar'); plt.show()`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I dont think there is a need for subplots

Comment: @Bharath Yeah I saw your answer... I guess not :-0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use pandas, i.e:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'a': {'L1':2, 'L2':5, 'L3':8},
    'b': {'L1':4, 'L2':7, 'L3':10},
    'c': {'L1':19, 'L2':0, 'L3':1},
}
pd.DataFrame(d).plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: output]

In your case you need dict keys in x-axis so you can use

```
pd.DataFrame(d).T.plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: I needed to have the keys on the x-axis not L1, L2 and L3 but I took your code and added a dataframe.transpose() and got exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks !

Comment: Oh I missed that part. Yeah we can transpose.

Comment: @MhamedJabri If the answer helped, don't forget to vote on it and accept the answer.

Comment: Any suggestion to plot a similar dictionary that does not contains the  "L1": , "L2":, ... names?
I am looking for a solution to a dictionary like this: d = {
    'a': [2, 5, 8],
    'b': [4, 7, 10],
    'c': [19, 0, 1],
}
And plot it by keys with the corresponding percentages in a barplot

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a solution without Pandas, seaborn can also plot dictionaries. All you need is to **rearrange the dictionary** to match the seaborn data format:

```
import seaborn as sb

d = {
    'x':    ['L1', 'L1',  'L1', 'L2', 'L2', 'L2', 'L3', 'L3', 'L3'],
    'y':    [   2,    4,   19,     5,    7,    0,    8,    10,   1],
    'group':[  'a',  'b', 'c',   'a',  'b',  'c',   'a',  'b',  'c']
}

sb.barplot(x='x', y='y', hue="group", data=d)
```

[image]

Note that `barplot` automatically groups both `x` and `group` fields. For example, replacing `L3` with `L2`,

```
d = {
    'x':    ['L1', 'L1',  'L1', 'L2', 'L2', 'L2', 'L2', 'L2', 'L2'],
    'y':    [   2,    4,   19,     5,    7,    0,    8,    10,   1],
    'group':[  'a',  'b', 'c',   'a',  'b',  'c',   'a',  'b',  'c']
}
```

we get:

[image]

Comment: The structure of the dictionary is not the same as in the question

Comment: @udion exactly. that's why I mentioned that the dictionary needs to be rearranged to match the seaborn data format